# Select Items Increase Incrementally from Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am populating a form from a MySQL database.  The purpose of the form is to create an "ordering form".

All items from the database are displaying correctly, but I am having a challenge with my one field.  Next to each item, there is a quantity that can be ordered in either quantities of 1 or 25. I need to create a drop-down selection the will give options of either 0, 25, 50, 75, 100, etc Or 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. depending on the multiplier column in my table.

The table structure is as follows:

```
Item Name | Multiplier | Price
Item 001  |     25     | 0.25
Item 002  |     1      | 1.50
Item 003  |     25     | 0.50
Item 004  |     1      | 2.25
Item 005  |     25     | 0.75
Item 006  |     25     | 0.50
```

In my drop down list under the quantity selection list the options should be incremented by the multiplier e.g

Item 001 Options --

```
<select name="quantity">
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50>50</option>
    <option value="75">75</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="125">125</option>
</select>
```

Item 002 Options --

```
<select name="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

This is what the HTML code would look like if I was not returning the table from the Database (http://www.techdesignlab.co.za/example.html):

```
<table border = 1> 
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 001</td>
        <td><img src=4521948.jpg height=50 align=center></img></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">0</option>        
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>        
                <option value="75">75</option>      
                <option value="100">100</option>  
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>0.25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 002</td>
        <td><img src=4211098.jpg height=50 align=center></img></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">0</option>        
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>        
                <option value="3">3</option>      
                <option value="4">4</option>  
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>1.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 003</td>
        <td><img src=pieces/300521.jpg height=50 align=center></img></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">0</option>        
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>        
                <option value="75">75</option>      
                <option value="100">100</option>  
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>0.50</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Question:** How do I get the options values to increase by the multiplier?
**Tried:**

```
$total=5000;
echo '<td><select>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['multiplier'].'">'.$row['multiplier'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select></td>';
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried ? What is your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your loop counter to multiply the value of `$row['multiplier']`:

```
$total = 5000;
echo '<td><select>';
for($i = 0; $i * $row['multiplier'] < $total; $i++) {
      $value = $i * $row['multiplier'];
      echo "<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
}
echo '</select></td>';
```

Alternatively you could just increment the loop variable by `$row['multiplier']`:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i += $row['multiplier']) {
      echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
}
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need. Only problem is me $Total Variable does not seem to be stopping at the indicated amount of 5000.

Comment: @LeonClaassen I wasn't sure how you were using `$total`. I will edit...

Comment: @LeonClaassen see my edit, I've given you a couple of possible solutions that use `$total` as the maximum option value.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the items from the table and do the for loop like below

```
<?php
foreach ($items as $item) {
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $item->name ?></td>
    <td><img src=4521948.jpg height=50 align=center></img></td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="0">0</option>        
            <option value="<?php echo ($item->multiplier * 1); ?>"><?php echo ($item->multiplier * 1); ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo ($item->multiplier * 2); ?>"><?php echo ($item->multiplier * 2); ?></option>        
            <option value="<?php echo ($item->multiplier * 3); ?>"><?php echo ($item->multiplier * 3); ?></option>      
            <option value="<?php echo ($item->multiplier * 4); ?>"><?php echo ($item->multiplier * 4); ?></option>  
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $item->price ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```